# Wordpress - class of “closed” had been added on pageload to the “acf-field-group-fields"

Tags: wordpress, class, debugging, advanced-custom-fields, display

None of my fields were displaying on the Edit Field Group page in the WP admin. I discovered a class of “closed” had been added on pageload to the “acf-field-group-fields”. If I remove the “closed” class, the fields will appear.

I updated the ACF plugin and still doesn't work.

Any idea what could have caused this?

SCREEN:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8zLR.png)

Comment: try disabling other plugins, some plugin conflict it seems

Comment: I have only Contact Form 7 plugin and Easy WP SMTP plugin, and yesterday all was ok and worked, but today suddenly my fields disappeared.
I found solution and add to my functions.php code:

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
function my_custom_fonts() {
      echo '<style>
          #acf-field-group-fields {display:block!important;}
         .handlediv {display:block!important;}
         .hndle ui-sortable-handle {display:block!important;}
         .inside{display:block!important;}
      </style>';
    }

but I don't know, if is a good solution ?